# Changing a chain of If-statements into a Switch-expression

Tags: java, if-statement, java-17, switch-expression

I'm trying to convert the below `if` *statement* into a `switch` *expression*.

```
public static int parseDays(String durationString) {
    String[] parts = durationString.split(" ");
    if (parts.length == 2) {
        return unitValueCalculation(parts[1], parts[0]);
    }
    else if (parts.length == 1)
    {
        if (parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("once")) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I've got:

```
 public static int parseDays(String durationString) {
       
        switch (durationString) {
            case durationString.split(" ").length  == 2 -> unitValueCalculation(parts[1], parts[2]);
        }
```

I'm not sure what to do about the case statement, though.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've provided can be made into a [`switch-expression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) like that:

```
public static int parseDays(String durationString) {
    String[] parts = durationString.split(" ");
    
    return switch(parts.length) {
        case 2 -> unitValueCalculation(parts[1], parts[0]);
        case 1 -> parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("once") ? 1 : 0;
        default -> 0;
    };
}
```

The length of the `parts` array should be used inside the parentheses `()` of the `switch`. And each particular length (`1` and `2`) should be used as a *case-constant*.

The `default` case covers all unspecified array sizes.